# Short record query with Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Can I modify the following query to make it more concise way using Django ORM?

```
queryset.filter((Q(from_date__lte=from_date) & \
                 Q(to_date__gt=from_date)) | \
                (Q(from_date__lte=to_date) & 
                 Q(to_date__gt=to_date)))
```

Here are some examples:

```
"from_date": "2014-05-11 08:00:00", 
"to_date": "2014-05-11 10:00:00",

"from_date": "2014-05-12 12:00:00", 
"to_date": "2014-05-12 15:00:00",
```

These are the dates in the database

If you submit

```
fromDate=2014-05-11 08:00:00
toDate=2014-05-11 13:00:00
```

should give me only the first date

```
"from_date": "2014-05-11 08:00:00", 
"to_date": "2014-05-11 10:00:00",
```

Here again, should give me only the first result

```
fromDate=2014-05-11 09:00:00
toDate=2014-05-11 13:00:00
```

If I submit the following date

```
fromDate=2014-05-11 07:00:00
toDate=2014-05-11 09:00:00
```

Again, only the first result should be taken

If you do so you can get both results

```
fromDate=2014-05-11 09:00:00
toDate=2014-05-12 13:00:00
```

I hope you understand what's the idea.

The query should remain the same logic!

Comment: You can use [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range) to search a date field between two dates, but it seems not is your case.

Comment: Can you show me how it looks? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you enforce that your `from_date` value is less than or equal to (or strictly less than, if appropriate) your `to_date`? That allows simplification if so. Also, are the `from_date` and `to_date` values on the model nullable?

Comment: from_date to always be less than to_date

Comment: Hmm. Actually, your query will not find results that are entirely within the new `from_date` and `to_date` values. Is that intended?

Comment: I edited my topic with some examples. I hope you understand what is required

Comment: With your example data, what result do you want if you submit 2014-05-11 07:00:00 as the from date and 2014-05-11 13:00:00 as the to date? That entirely overlaps one record and does not intersect the other.

Comment: This should give me only the first entry. Exactly fully cover it only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queryset.filter(to_date__gt=from_date, from_date__lt=to_date)
```

That is, to be returned the event must end after the new event starts and must start before the new event ends. Anything that ends before the new from_date is not returned, neither is anything that doesn't start until after it ends.

That does not precisely match your original query, but it does match the behavior described in the comments for when there's a record in the database that is entirely within the range set by the new dates.

Comment: This example does not do what it should. He takes and dates are located on another day.

Comment: Tweaked it a bit. Date range logic always takes more thought than it seems like it should.

Comment: I request that as at the date which is set if the base is covered this time it appears.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that comment. Can you provide an example that the above does not work with?

Comment: If submit that these dates: ***fromDate = 2014-05-11 07:00:00*** and
***toDate = 2014-05-11 09:00:00*** with your query get all the dates, but I want only the first, only those that fall within this range.

Comment: That set of dates will not return the second date using the above query, because it will not pass the `from_date__lt=2014-05-11 09:00:00` test. `2014-05-12 12:00:00` is not less than any time from the 11th.

Comment: To apologize. The query was previously with exclude, so I'm confused.

Comment: Yeah, I had first written it as an `exclude`, refactored it to use `or`'d `Q` objects in the `exclude`, then remembered that `~(a or b) == ~a and ~b`. Since Django's queries express `and`ed constraints more concisely, `filter` it is.